# Assembly: add 1 to parameter

Tags: assembly

```
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], edi
  mov edi, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
  add edi, 1
  mov eax, edi
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Hello! I'm studying assembly and I'm having trouble understanding two things:

1. Why do we use rbp? I know it's a register that may not be modified by the callee, but I don't see why it cannot be modified, and why we don't just use rsp. Also, shouln't it be rbx instead of rbp?
2. From line 3-4, why do we move the element in edi to [rbp-4], and then move it back to edi again? Also, shouln't it be mov rbp-4, [edi] instead of [rbp-4], edi?

Comment: Because the code is not optimized.

Comment: rbp is preserved by the callee because it is required by the x86-64 calling convention.

Comment: It could use rbx instead of rbp, but rbp is used by convention. (Also using rbp implicitly uses the stack segment, which is almost entirely irrelevant for 64-bit code.)

Comment: `mov rbp-4, [edi]` isn't valid code, but what did you think it might mean?

Answer (score 1):

**For both questions** the answer is the compiler optimization:

In principle there are three ways to optimize compiling:

1. The code produced should be as short as possible
2. The code produced should execute as fast as possible
3. The process of compiling should be as fast as possible

(Normally you would not call method 3 an "optimization".)

By default a C compiler does the third method: It *always* uses the same "default" elements (e.g. "push ebp" at the start of a function) which will *always* work so the compiler always does the same steps. This makes the process of compiling easier.

**Details about question 1:**

For 16-bit software the use of the `bp` register was nearly not avoidable because there was no instruction (with exception of `push` and `pop` of course) which was able to access the memory at the `sp` register in 16-bit code.

In 64-bit code you could always use `[rsp - 4]` instead of `[rbp - 4]` however in the case of an `alloca()` instruction this would not be possible any more.

To save time (when using optimization type 3) the compiler will write the `push rbp` and `mov rbp, rsp` instructions to the file *before* it knows if there is an `alloca()` instruction or not.

**Details about question 2:**

When using optimization methods 1 or 2 the compiler (I tried the GNU compiler coming with Linux) will generate code like this:

```
lea eax, [rbp + 1]
ret
```

However to do so the compiler has to "remember" which register currently contains which value. This costs time while compiling...

Therefore when using "optimization" method 3 the compiler will do what is the *default* which will *always* work in any situation:

Write all arguments to the stack and reading all local variables (including arguments) from the stack...

> Also, shouln't it be `mov rbp-4, [edi]` instead of `[rbp-4], edi`?

The square brackets mean: Use a memory location instead of a value.

No square brackets mean that no memory is used.

So `mov [rbp-4], edi` means: Write the value of `edi` to the memory location at the address `rbp-4`.

A real x86-64 CPU does not support this instruction but we could run the instruction `mov [edi], rbp-4` in some simulator. The instruction would write the value `rbp-4` to the memory location at the address `edi`.

The instruction `mov rbp-4, [edi]` however would mean: "Read the value from the memory location at the address `edi` ..." (this would be possible) "... and write that value to `rbp-4`" (**not**: "to the memory at the address `rbp-4`").

The CPU had to solve an equation in one single instruction...

Comment: The value is stored into the temporary memory (and then reloaded) also for debugging purposes, so high-level debug view can inspect values of variables between different lines of original source. If the modified value would be kept only in registers, as in optimized code, the variable view would still show old value.